# unistall android application programmatically

Tags: android, uninstallation, android-package-managers

I want to be able to allow my users to uninstall application from my application. Just like what Google Play Store allow to their users(Please below image)

[image]

the main question is that how can define a button that by pressing it we can uninstall an app by giving the package name or some other info.Just like the uninstall button on the image.

Comment: have a look thia                                              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("package:" + app_pkg_name));
  startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:app package name"));
startActivity(intent);
```

If this doesn't work then
change intent to:

```
Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE);
```

and set datatype as:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("package:" + your app package name));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
Intent intent = null;
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE);
} else {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
}

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null));
if(intent.resolveActivity(getActivity( ).getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin
// This is for kotlin

```
 < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES" />
```

> Code

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE)
intent.data = Uri.parse("package:"+app_package_name)
startActivity(intent)
// note app package name should be given properly.
```

Comment: It's good practice to put code or expression in quotes \` like `<uses-permission ...>`. Code is much easier to read and eye-catch

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This is very similar to the solution in the accepted answer. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.