# Method onActivityResult does not get called and when called resultCode always zero

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I am trying to get the result from a system dialog. Meaning a dialog that I have no control over.

My onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = MainActivity.this;

    //Floating Action Button for uninstalling applications
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < checkValues.length; i++)
            {
                //Uninstall any true values
                if(checkValues[i] == 1)
                {
                    String appName = AppContent.getItem(i).pkgName;

                    Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:"+ appName);
                    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, packageUri);
                    startActivity(uninstallIntent);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //Disappear the button until the user makes a selection.
    fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

My onActivityResult method :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println("ACTIVITY RESULT : " + resultCode + " ----- ACTIVITY REQUEST CODE : " + requestCode);

}
```

The idea is that once the intent starts and the user is presented with the choice of uninstalling the app or cancelling the uninstall, that onActivityResult would give me their choice based on the resultCode integer.

Where I run into issues is that onActivityResult never gets called. I tried fixing that issue by using:

```
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent) 
context.startActivity(intent)
```

I though that my problem was that calling it from an anon class was not triggering the onActivityResult method but even this fails. I then tried using

```
startActivityForResult(intent, anyNumberHere)
```

This actually triggers the onActivityResult method, however the resultCode parameter is always zero. It does not matter if the user clicks cancel or uninstall. This does not help me because I need to know their choice so I can execute more code down the line based on it.

I read about this issue and quite a few people had problems with the settings in the AndroidManifest.xml file so I am posting mine here as well for completeness.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="app.app.app"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme">

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358672/unistall-android-application-programmatically

Comment: My intent works perfectly fine. The problem I am having is that the resultCode that i get from onActivityResult is always zero. This means I do not know if the user chose to cancel or uninstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

defile class variable

```
int UNINSTALL_REQUEST = 111 // or any number.
```

start your activity like this way

```
startActivityForResult(uninstallIntent, UNINSTALL_REQUEST);
```

and on activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println("ACTIVITY RESULT : " + resultCode + " ----- ACTIVITY  REQUEST CODE : " + requestCode);  
    // request code should be same as UNINSTALL_REQUEST to confirm method is called for which activity.

}
```

Comment: I have already done this. While this does fix the issue of the onActivityResult not getting called, its does not fix the fact that resultCode is still zero whether the user chooses to cancel or uninstall the app. Therefore, I cannot get the needed information which is to know if they chose cancel or uninstall.